# Conditional Breakpoints for Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have the following layout:

[image: layout]

This is the code I used:

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-xl fluid class="py-0 mb-5">
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 lg8>
                        <v-container class="pa-0 mb-5">
                            <v-layout>
                                <v-flex xs12 class="py-0">
                                    <v-subheader class="pa-0 mb-3">
                                        Title 1
                                    </v-subheader>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                            <v-layout wrap>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4 lg6>
                                    Content 1
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md8 lg6>
                                    Content 2
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs12 lg4>
                        <v-container class="pa-0">
                            <v-layout row>
                                <v-flex xs12 class="py-0">
                                    <v-subheader class="pa-0 mb-3">
                                        Title 2
                                    </v-subheader>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                            <v-layout row>
                                <v-flex xs12>
                                    Content 3
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Very simple and it works for what I need it to do. However, now I have the following problem... **"Content 2" might not exist**. When "Content 2" doesn't exist, this will happen:

[image]

But I actually want this to happen:

[image: layout]

Is there a way I can control the breakpoints? I would like to somehow switch between `lg4` and `lg8` depending on if I have a "Content 2" or not. I thought about creating two v-flexes, one with `lg4` and one with `lg8`, showing only one or the other, but I don't want to repeat my code and creating a new component also isn't possible for me.

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
<v-flex v-if="content2Exists" xs12 lg8>
<v-flex v-else xs12 lg4>
    Blabla...
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try a condition inside the `lg(x)` prop as follows :

```
  <v-flex  xs12 :lg4="!content2Exists" :lg8="content2Exists">
```